# Problems in initializing a ODataSingleProcessor in Apache Olingo

Tags: java, apache, odata, olingo

I have been trying to implement the tombstone feature in my odata app,
I've extended an **ODataSingleProcessor** and a **ODataServiceFactory**, and I also have a **ODataJPAServiceFactory**, where a was trying to use the initializeODataJPAContext method(still didn't work).

My question really is: Where do I initialize the **readEntitySet** method of the **OdataSingleProcessor**? 
I already read a ton of tutorials and still didn't find anything.

**ODataSingleProcessor**

```
 public class CustomODataSingleProcessor extends ODataSingleProcessor {


public CustomODataSingleProcessor(ODataContext oDataContext){
        setContext(oDataContext);
}


CustomServiceFactory factory = new CustomServiceFactory();
TombstoneCallback tombstoneCallback;

@Override
public ODataResponse readEntitySet(final GetEntitySetUriInfo uriInfo, final String contentType)
        throws ODataException {
    tombstoneCallback = factory.getCallback(TombstoneCallback.class);

    Map<String, ODataCallback> callbacks = new HashMap<String, ODataCallback>();
    callbacks.put(TombstoneCallback.CALLBACK_KEY_TOMBSTONE, tombstoneCallback);

    URI uri =  getContext().getPathInfo().getServiceRoot();
    //tombstoneCallback.getTombstoneCallbackResult().getDeletedEntriesData();
    EntityProviderWriteProperties properties = EntityProviderWriteProperties.serviceRoot(uri)
                                                                            .callbacks(callbacks).build();

    final ODataResponse response = new JsonEntityProvider()
                                        .writeFeed(uriInfo.getTargetEntitySet(), getData(uriInfo), properties);

    return response;
}

private List<Map<String, Object>> getData(GetEntitySetUriInfo uriInfo) throws EdmException {

    List<Map<String, Object>> values = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

    HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    for (String pName : uriInfo.getTargetEntitySet().getEntityType().getPropertyNames()) {

        EdmProperty property = (EdmProperty) uriInfo.getTargetEntitySet().getEntityType().getProperty(pName);
        Object mappedPropertyName = property.getMapping().getObject();

        data.put(pName, mappedPropertyName);
        values.add(data);

    }

    return values;
}
```

**ODataServiceFactory**

```
public class CustomODataServiceFactory  extends ODataServiceFactory{
private ODataJPAContext oDataJPAContext;
  private ODataContext oDataContext;
  private boolean setDetailErrors = false;
  private OnJPAWriteContent onJPAWriteContent = null;
  private ODataJPATransaction oDataJPATransaction = null;

  public CustomODataServiceFactory(ODataJPAContext oDataJPAContext) {
      this.oDataJPAContext = oDataJPAContext;
}

  @Override
  public final ODataService createService(final ODataContext ctx) throws ODataException {

    oDataContext = ctx;

    validatePreConditions();

    ODataJPAFactory factory = ODataJPAFactory.createFactory();
    ODataJPAAccessFactory accessFactory = factory.getODataJPAAccessFactory();

    // OData JPA Processor
    if (oDataJPAContext.getODataContext() == null) {
      oDataJPAContext.setODataContext(ctx);
    }

    //Processor Customizado
    ODataSingleProcessor odataJPAProcessor = new CustomODataSingleProcessor(ctx);

    // OData Entity Data Model Provider based on JPA
    EdmProvider edmProvider = accessFactory.createJPAEdmProvider(oDataJPAContext);

    return createODataSingleProcessorService(edmProvider, odataJPAProcessor);
  }

  public ODataSingleProcessor createCustomODataProcessor(ODataJPAContext oDataJPAContext) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public ODataService createODataSingleProcessorService(EdmProvider provider, ODataSingleProcessor processor) {
    return super.createODataSingleProcessorService(provider, processor);
}

/**
   * @return an instance of type {@link ODataJPAContext}
   * @throws ODataJPARuntimeException
   */
  public final ODataJPAContext getODataJPAContext() throws ODataJPARuntimeException {
    if (oDataJPAContext == null) {
      oDataJPAContext = ODataJPAFactory.createFactory().getODataJPAAccessFactory().createODataJPAContext();
    }
    if (oDataContext != null) {
      oDataJPAContext.setODataContext(oDataContext);
    }
    return oDataJPAContext;

  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public <T extends ODataCallback> T getCallback(final Class<T> callbackInterface) {
    if (setDetailErrors == true) {
      if (callbackInterface.isAssignableFrom(ODataErrorCallback.class)) {
        return (T) new ODataJPAErrorCallback();
      }
    }
    if (onJPAWriteContent != null) {
      if (callbackInterface.isAssignableFrom(OnJPAWriteContent.class)) {
        return (T) onJPAWriteContent;
      }
    }
    if (oDataJPATransaction != null) {
      if (callbackInterface.isAssignableFrom(ODataJPATransaction.class)) {
        return (T) oDataJPATransaction;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  /**
   * The methods sets the context with a callback implementation for JPA provider specific content.
   * For details refer to {@link org.apache.olingo.odata2.jpa.processor.api.OnJPAWriteContent}
   * @param onJPAWriteContent is an instance of type
   * {@link org.apache.olingo.odata2.jpa.processor.api.OnJPAWriteContent}
   */
  protected void setOnWriteJPAContent(final OnJPAWriteContent onJPAWriteContent) {
    this.onJPAWriteContent = onJPAWriteContent;
  }

  /**
   * The methods sets the context with a callback implementation for JPA transaction specific content.
   * For details refer to {@link ODataJPATransaction}
   * @param oDataJPATransaction is an instance of type
   * {@link org.apache.olingo.odata2.jpa.processor.api.ODataJPATransaction}
   */
  protected void setODataJPATransaction(final ODataJPATransaction oDataJPATransaction) {
    this.oDataJPATransaction = oDataJPATransaction;
  }


  protected void setDetailErrors(final boolean setDetailErrors) {
    this.setDetailErrors = setDetailErrors;
  }

  private void validatePreConditions() throws ODataJPARuntimeException {

    if (oDataJPAContext.getEntityManager() == null) {
      throw ODataJPARuntimeException.throwException(ODataJPARuntimeException.ENTITY_MANAGER_NOT_INITIALIZED, null);
    }

  }
```

**ODataJPAServiceFactory**

```
public class CustomServiceFactory extends ODataJPAServiceFactory {
public final OnJPAWriteContent onDBWriteContent = new OnDBWriteContent();

@Override
public ODataJPAContext initializeODataJPAContext() throws ODataJPARuntimeException {

    ODataJPAContext oDataJPAContext = getODataJPAContext();

    oDataJPAContext.setEntityManagerFactory(JPAUtil.getEntityManagerFactory());

    oDataJPAContext.setPersistenceUnitName(JPAEntityManagerFactory.PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);

    oDataJPAContext.setJPAEdmExtension(new DefaultEntityProcessingExtension());



    setOnWriteJPAContent(onDBWriteContent);

    return oDataJPAContext;
}

public <T extends ODataCallback> T getCallback(final Class<T> callbackInterface) {
    T callback = null;

    if (callbackInterface.isAssignableFrom(CustomDebugCallback.class)) {
        callback = (T) new CustomDebugCallback();
    } else {
        callback = (T) super.getCallback(callbackInterface);
    }

    return callback;
}

@Override
public ODataService createODataSingleProcessorService(EdmProvider provider, ODataSingleProcessor processor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ODataSingleProcessorService service = (ODataSingleProcessorService) super.createODataSingleProcessorService(
            provider, processor);

    return service;
}

public class OnDBWriteContent implements OnJPAWriteContent {

    @Override
    public Blob getJPABlob(byte[] binaryData) throws ODataJPARuntimeException {
        try {
            return new JDBCBlob(binaryData);
        } catch (SerialException e) {
            ODataJPARuntimeException.throwException(ODataJPARuntimeException.INNER_EXCEPTION, e);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            ODataJPARuntimeException.throwException(ODataJPARuntimeException.INNER_EXCEPTION, e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Clob getJPAClob(char[] characterData) throws ODataJPARuntimeException {
        try {
            return new JDBCClob(new String(characterData));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            ODataJPARuntimeException.throwException(ODataJPARuntimeException.INNER_EXCEPTION, e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, have you get any success in this problem? I am interesting in `OnDBWriteContent` and especially implementation for `JDBCBlob`. Maybe you can help me by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62813234/how-to-handle-blob-and-clob-in-olingo-v2).